# What is the meaning of the signs beside variable in PhpStorm debugger frame

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm

[image]

What do these signs wrapped by red box exactly mean? Triangle means variable in stack and circle means variable in heap?

Comment: It's a bit out of date (official help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debug-tool-window-variables.html) ... but those icons mean the variable type: array, object, lambda function, primitive type (integer/float/string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from what I've seen in Java and my uses of IntelliJ:

- Triangle => array
- Circle => Object
- lambda => anonymous function or actual lambda (if your language supports them)
- heart: primitive

[Here is a list of icons](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/icons-reference.html) that the editor itself will display, and [here's what the debugger will show](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window-variables.html).  They're not radically different across IDEs unless your language is using a very specific feature.